# UIVIEW transform from top to bottom

Tags: ios, uiview, uianimation

I want to create `UIView` animation direction from top to bottom, but after I tried for two days it i'm surrrender

here's my code

```
- (IBAction)goAction:(id)sender 
{
    primaryView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        secondaryView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, secondaryView.frame.size.width, secondaryView.frame.size.height);

        CALayer *layer = primaryView.layer;
        layer.zPosition = -4000;
        CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m21 = 1.0 / -300;
        layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 10.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);            
        primaryShadeView.alpha = 0.35;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            primaryView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9,0.9);
            primaryShadeView.alpha = 0.5;
        }];
    }];
}
```

this direction.... bottom to top... hope you all can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially alloc the view at a position such that it falls above the navigation bar.

```
CGRectMake(0, 100, secondaryView.frame.size.width, secondaryView.frame.size.height);
```

here change the value 100 to a value that is a negative value enough to hide your allocated view. During showing with animation  use the same  CGRectMake parameters with only change in "y", give postion to show it on your screen. On nNext click hide it in same way.

Does that make sense?

Here is the sample:

in your button action :

```
{
    if(!youNewView)
    {
        youNewView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, -220(depends on your view height), 320, 300) ];
      //add additional properties you need to add here
        [self.View addSubview:youNewView];
    }

     [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:newView cache:YES];
     [UIView commitAnimations];

else
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        newView.frame = CGRectMake(newView.frame.origin.x, -210, myPicker.frame.size.width, newView.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [newView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I have successfully did it with this method.if you are stuck I will help you with code. try it

Comment: yep,,, trying now,,, still otw to home :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                              self.view.frame.size.height,
                                              self.view.frame.size.width,
                                              self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Please Try this One , it is work for me.